# Как убедиться, что constexpr действительно вычисляется во время компиляции?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

Очередной чисто теоретический вопрос - а как убедиться, что `constexpr` действительно вычисляется во время компиляции? Похоже, что по крайней мере Visual C++, не сумев справиться с `constexpr`-функцией, никак об этом не сообщает.

Как паллиатив для целочисленного результата можно применить класс-повторилку, типа

```
template <int N>
struct val
{
    static int const value = N;
};
```

и тогда для

```
constexpr int complexFunc(){...}
```

результат использовать как

```
val<complexFunc()>::value
```

Но это и громоздко, и ограниченно пригодно...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`constexpr` гарантирует что функция может быть вызвана на этапе компиляции, если она вызвана в контексте, в котором разрешены только выражения времени компиляции - параметры шаблона, constexpr переменные, другие constexpr функции, размер массива, целочисленные static const члены которые инициализированы при объявлении, инициализаторы в enum.

По этому достаточно использовать constexpr переменные, тогда они будут вычислены на этапе компиляции:

```
constexpr int f() { return 42; }

int main() {
    constexpr int x = f();
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Ага, логично, спасибо!